# Is it likely that this single skin brick wall can support a large kitchen cabinet?

Tags: walls, garage, brick, storage

[image: Garage wall]

I would like to hang an 80cm x 80cm x 37cm cabinet on this single skin brick wall (where the ladders are currently hanging). The bricks are 10cm deep. The span of wall, each side of the pier, is ~300cm.

The cabinet weighs ~30kg, and would be attached to the wall with a steel hanging rail (with x4 6cm deep fixings).

Inside the cabinet I will store cleaning products, clothes, etc.

I have no concerns about the strength of the individual fixings, but I'm wondering if it's wise to attach heavy objects to such a large "skin" of single brick.

I cannot find any online resources for recommended maximum loads on this type of wall (or any wall, in fact).

Comment: What's on the other side of the bricks?

Comment: Nothing (an alleyway).

Comment: Just a comment because I don't have specifics, but I **highly doubt** this would be a problem **at all**. Brick walls are built like...brick walls.

Comment: With proper anchors you should be fine the cabinet would fail before a brick wall would give way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have no qualms hanging a kitchen wall cabinet on a single skin garage wall. 37cm deep sounds like a base cabinet. That's going to give scope for larger loads.

Should still be fine though. The closer you hang it to one of the piers, the better.

Comment: The cabinet has been on the wall for just over a week now.  I ended up hanging it next to the pier.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is nothing on the other side of the brick wall, you may want to consider drilling a hole *through* the wall, and securing the cabinet with nuts, bolts, and washers.  Either get machined bolts that are the proper length depending on your wall+cabinet, or, buy some all-thread and cut it yourself.  This may sound like overkill but some brick can be brittle and it’s hard for threads to “catch”.